# using javascript regexp to match log file tail

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, server-application

hi I need to use [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to vaildate an ajax call to an output log on a server - to check if a process therin is "finished". I have a php file that can give the last line of the log no mater what. Ajax goes and gets it 5 times a second. But I need to client side ratify it when done. The last line of the log (when finished) will be:

Just like any of these examples either "Total time: 2 seconds" or "Total time: 17 seconds" or "Total time: 1 minutes" I would like a regex to be able to identify that string no matter what the number

Comment: The regex you need is "Total time: \d+ (seconds|minutes)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Total time: \d{1,} (seconds|minutes)/`

you can add an upper limit after the `1,` if you'd like to limit the number to 2-4 digits or whatever you want.

Comment: You could anchor it also to prevent substring matches

Comment: how do you mean Alex?